# Addition works, subtraction doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare("UPDATE comments SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE ? LIKE concat(path, '%')");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $path);
$stmt->execute();
```

Where `$path` is something like `1/2/3/`.

This query increments the counter fine for each result, but if I change the query to subtract (`counter = counter - 1`), it won't actually subtract and I'm not sure why. After all, I'm only changing that one operator.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try "counter + -1" just to see what happens.

Comment: @barrycarter Still didn't fix the issue. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that, because I was using unsigned integers for the `counter`, if the counter was already set to 0, the query wouldn't work.

So either you have to check that counter doesn't equal 0 or make it signed.

Comment: Define "wouldn't work". What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way, which is the method I use:

```
SET `counter` = (`counter` - 1)
```

and another method:

```
SET counter = (counter-1)
```

EDIT:

your `WHERE` clause should be more precise.

I.e.: `WHERE column=column_to_change` instead of just `WHERE ?`

Here's my working piece of code:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `fieldname` = (`fieldname` - 1) WHERE `some_id` = 1
```

Comment: Really? That's what I use myself and it works. @Bagwell  You may need to use a more precise method like `WHERE column=column_to_change` which is what I have. Instead of `WHERE ?`

Comment: Plus, I honestly don't know who or why downvoted this, it's "working code" from one of my scripts.

Comment: I found out the issue. It's because I'm using unsigned integers and if the counter was already at 0 and I tried subtracting, it wouldn't actually work.

Comment: Funny you should say that, I thought about that earlier, but was away from my computer. I had also thought of adding a condition to check if the counter was already set to zero. @Bagwell - Glad to see you found your solution.